# N1QL to get org Id of the employee with id 2 in both the org doc

Tags: sql++

```
  "orgId": 1,
  "orgName":"orgOne"
  "empList": [
    {
    "empId": 1,
    "empName":"emp1"    
      },
    {
    "empId": 2,
    "empName":"emp2"    
      },
    {
    "empId": 3,
    "empName":"emp3"    
      }  
    ]
},
{
  "orgId": 2,
  "orgName":"orgTwo"
  "empList": [    
    {
    "empId": 2,
    "empName":"emp2"    
      },{
    "empId": 3,
    "empName":"emp3"    
      }     
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following query gives orgId for empId =2

```
SELECT  d.orgId
FROM default AS d
WHERE ANY e IN d.empList SATISFIES e.empId = 2 END;
```

If you are looking different could you explain more details.